# Can I give element ID the name null or does it cause problems?

Tags: html

I want to make a simple calculator using html and javascript.

number 0 is called "null" in german, so i wanted to give the button ID that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can declare it "null". It is just a string, not the JavaScript equivalent [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null).

All ASCII letters are okay for identifiers, see
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with giving it an id of null as HTML doesn't watch out for language in id as it is just a string.

Example:

```js
document.getElementById("null").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("con").innerHTML = "null";
}
```

```html
<button id="null">0</button>
<p id="con">Click the button</p>
```